# Cant convert yolov4 tiny to tf model cannot - cannot reshape array of size 607322 into shape (256,384,3,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

I've a custom yolov4-tiny model that I have trained with the following command

```
./darknet.exe detector train ./data/device.data ./cfg/yolov4-tiny-device.cfg ./yolov4-tiny.conv.29
```

but I can't convert the model to tensorflow using the following repo
https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite

forsome reason why I try to convert using the following command

```
py ./save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4-tiny-device_last.weights --output ./checkpoint/yolov4-tiny-device-416 --input_size 416  --model yolov4 --tiny
```

I recive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\save_model.py", line 68, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\save_model.py", line 64, in main
    save_tf()
  File ".\save_model.py", line 59, in save_tf
    utils.load_weights(model, FLAGS.weights, FLAGS.model, FLAGS.tiny)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\VSCProjects\tensorflow-yolov4-tflite\core\utils.py", line 64, in load_weights
    conv_weights = conv_weights.reshape(conv_shape).transpose([2, 3, 1, 0])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 607322 into shape (256,384,3,3)
```

I've changed the __C.YOLO.CLASSES to my classs file and my classes file is just one line for one class.

I've done the same proccess for a normal yolov4 model and it worked completly fine.

How can I fix the following error and convert my model to tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `--framework tflite` flag in for `save_model.py` for conversion to tflite. Though I am not sure this is the reason. Sample command for conversion that worked for me,

```
!python save_model.py \
--weights "yolov4-tiny-obj_best.weights" \
--output "checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416" \
--input_size 416 --model yolov4 --tiny --framework tflite
```

I had this problem previously due to hardcoded `__C.YOLO.CLASSES` to a file. The error could be due to the path to file is wrong or missing flag.

I have some [conversion instructions here](https://github.com/quickgrid/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) for YoloV4 tiny based on similar issues.

Similar question, [cannot reshape array of size 1665179 into shape (512,512,3,3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406263/cannot-reshape-array-of-size-1665179-into-shape-512-512-3-3/64598514#64598514).